# Replacing a String in byte[] pdf file using c#

Tags: asp.net, pdf, memorystream

I'm downloading a pdf file from FTP server. I need to find a string and replace it, but when I try to convert the byte[] to string. It returns a non sense string.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url = "ftp://myftp.com/doc.pdf";
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
byte[] newFileData = client.DownloadData(url);

string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData, 0, newFileData.Length);
// This return a odd string

// I would like to replace, for example, all the occurrences of #TEST# to "ABC"

MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
pdfStream.Write(newFileData, 0, newFileData.Length);
pdfStream.Position = 0;

return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
```

Thanks

Comment: A pdf file (usually)  is not a plain text file. Obviously. Thus, simply treating it as a string and replacing some parts of it will merely damage it. To process pdf files you need a library that understands pdfs. But even then your task *to find a string and replace it* very likely won't be easy to implement. Pdf is a format for final document appearances, not for document editing. For generic pdfs it can already be hard to find the operations drawing specific texts (encodings can be arbitrary) , and replacing can have its issues, too (not all characters present, no content reflow).

Comment: I got it. So, what I want to do is impossible? I just want to auto populate my pdf documents

Comment: **A** *So, what I want to do is impossible?* - First of all it is virtually impossible without a decent PDF library. **B** *I just want to auto populate my pdf documents* - For that one does not use such variables but instead PDF form fields.